# Change ggplot2 + geom_map color scale from lighter color to darker

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've following code which plots Murder rates in different US states given in the USArrests dataset in R.

```
library(ggplot2)
crimes <-data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)

states_map <-map_data("state")

ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) +
  geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), map = states_map) +
  expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
```

In the map, Lower values are shown in darker tones and Higher values in Lighter. I want to reverse this i.e. lower values in lighter tones and higher in Darker tones.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the link to the plot]

Comment: Probably `+ scale_fill_gradient(low="#56B1F7", high="#132B43")`, where I've reversed the default colors, but you can of course set the specific colors you want.

Comment: Read the documentation for [?scale_fill_gradient](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html)